# boton funciona solo se ejecuta una vez sin que salga error, deberian ser n clicks

Tags: javascript

Solo funciona el 1er click despues aparece error
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')**
justo en esta linea sale el error
document.getElementById("PRE_" +id).value=itemCarrito.cantidad;
lo que trata de hacer mi funcion es sumar 1 mas a la cantidad si esque esta repetido
sino pues agrega al carro

```
printf('<td class="td"><button  class="button" onclick="(e)=> addToCarritoItem(e,'. $e->id_productos . ')">Añadir</button></td>');
   let carrito = []
     var arreglo=[]  
function addToCarritoItem(e,id){

    const button=e.target
    const item = button.closest('.tr');
    
    const id_prod = item.querySelector('.id_n').textContent;
  const codigo = item.querySelector('.codigo').textContent;
  const nombre = item.querySelector('.nombre').textContent;

  const Productos = {
    id: id_prod,
    codigo: codigo,
    nombre: nombre
  }

  let itemProductos = Productos;
  arreglo.push(itemProductos)
 

  let itemProducto =arreglo.findLast(({id_a}) => id_a === id);
 
  let itemCarrito = carrito.findLast(({id_a}) => id_a === id);
  
  if(itemCarrito){
    //console.log("Producto ya existe en carrito");
   if (itemProducto.cantidad_disponible<=itemCarrito.cantidad){
     return;
   }
  itemCarrito.cantidad++;
   document.getElementById("PRE_" +id).value=itemCarrito.cantidad;
 }
 else{
   itemCarrito = structuredClone(itemProducto); //creamos un clon para agregarlo al carrito
   itemCarrito.cantidad=1;
   itemCarrito.precio=0;
   carrito.push(itemCarrito);
   
   //renderiza (agrega) un producto a la tabla de carrito
   carrito_content.innerHTML+= interpolate(templateRowCarrito.innerHTML,itemCarrito);
 }
 }
```

Comment: ¿Estás _depurando_ tu código? Ya van varias preguntas similares (no iguales) y que además no tienen respuesta...

Comment: haber si me puedes ayudar como recupero  printf('<td class="td"><button  class="button" onclick="(e)=> addToCarritoItem(e,'. $e->id_productos . ')">Añadir</button></td>');                            <button  class="button" onclick="(e)=>addToCarritoItem(e,15)">Añadir</button> ese numero como lo llevo a la fucion y poder utilizarlo en dicha funcion, cabe destacar que puede ser cualquier numero mas alto o mas bajo

Comment: ¿A qué clic te refieres? La pregunta solo tiene javascript y en javascript no hay nada a lo qué hacerle clic. ¿No hará falta HTML en tu [mcve]? Es decir, el ejemplo está incompleto...

Comment: como se puede notar hay 2 parametros en la funcion cel boton una llamada e y otra que es un numero pero este lo trato de pasar al la funcion como id pero me dice undefined